# Plaintext avatar search

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have an avatar command that allows you to look up a member to get their avatar in Discord. The problem is that anytime I run the command with any arguments (implying you wanna find someone else's avatar, it sends a blank embed. It works fine sending the message author avatar, but not anyone else's.

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  let mem = args.join(' ');
  let memb = message.guild.members.find(m => [m.displayName.toLowerCase(), m.user.username.toLowerCase()].includes(mem.toLowerCase()));

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setImage(memb ? memb.displayAvatarURL : message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor(client.config.embedColor);

  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're trying to use `GuildMember.displayAvatarURL`, but that is a `User` property: try using `memb.user.displayAvatarURL`:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  let mem = args.join(' ');
  let memb = message.guild.members.find(m => [m.displayName.toLowerCase(), m.user.username.toLowerCase()].includes(mem.toLowerCase()));

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setImage(memb ? memb.user.displayAvatarURL : message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor(client.config.embedColor);

  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the answer as I was stumped. You, my friend, are a miracle worker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it so you type in the users' name, just make the command take a tagged user like so;

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.mentions.users.first()) return no.mention.function();
    let member = message.mentions.users.first();
    let memberAvatar = member.avatarURL;
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(client.config.embedColor)
        .setImage(memberAvatar);
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I specfically am avoiding that so I do not have to ping people.